# Passing ajax variable to more than one wordpress plugin function

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm trying to get information from the front end of my Wordpress site, I used ajax to do that, it gave me the ability to use the data in one of my plugin functions, but in my case I want to use this data in more than just one function.

```
add_action( 'admin_footer', 'my_action_javascript' ); 

function my_action_javascript() { ?>
    <script type="text/javascript" >
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

        var data = {
            'action': 'my_action',
            'whatever': 1234
        };

        jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data);
    });
    </script> <?php
}

add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action' );

function my_action() {

    $whatever = $_POST['whatever'];

}
```

In other words I need to use `$_POST['whatever']` in other functions in my plugin not only `my_action()` function, I tried using PHP global variables like so , but it didn't workout:

```
$whatever;
function my_action(){
    global $whatever = $_POST['whatever'];
}
function my_other_function(){
   global $whatever;
   if(isset($whatever)){
       echo $whatever;
   }
}
```

Comment: Interesting... I don't think either a class would hold the value, but I'm not really sure. As a workaround you could store the value on a transient or a cookie.